# What is this Javascrip/node variable/constant assinging notation/syntax called ?

Tags: javascript, node.js, syntax, notation

I've been trying to find out what this notation is called so I can better google it. It's from the gmail api node example but wont run for me.

```
const {client_secret, client_id, redirect_uris} = credentials.installed;
```

I *think* this is the correct stackexchange site for this, but if I'm wrong, happy to relocate it to a more appropriate one.

Comment: Object destructuring- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is [Destructuring Assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)